# Ckan Plugin for News and Events

Tags: plugins, jinja2, ckan

I am looking to find a Ckan plugin for posting updates and upcoming events to my website. Just like is in https://www.europeandataportal.eu/en//

I have tried to look through the extensions list provided but not able to find one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ckanext-pages](https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-pages).
This extension allows you to easily add simple pages, that you can use for publishing news or events. If that doesn't feet your needs you can extend the ckan and create your own custom extension.